# Returning an exe file from server and downloading on client via browser

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to send an exe file from the server to the client.
The file contents come in the form of byte array.
Then i am trying to recreate the `.exe` file on the client machine again.
On server side I am returning file contents as 
 '`application/octet-stream`', `'Content':bytearray`

I am using an ajax call of following type to get file contents.

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'https://myurl,
cache : false,
success : function(data) {
var myBlob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
              var uri = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(myBlob);

              // var outputFile = window.prompt("Saving .log file of rows from different modalities") || 'export';
                var  outputFile = "utility"+ '.exe'
               var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
               downloadLink.href = uri;
               downloadLink.download =outputFile;

               document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
               downloadLink.click();
               document.body.removeChild(downloadLink); 
cnt++;
/* }); */
},

error : (function(message) {
debugger;
console.log('message ' +message)
}),

statusCode : {
404 : function() {
alert("page not found");
}
}
});
```

But when the file gets downloaded the size of the file is big.
for ex original file `192kbs`
       downloaded file `320 kbs`
Also I am getting the following exception after running the exe:
The version of file is not compatible with version of windows you are running  on `32/64`

Please if anybody can help resolve this issue

**The following is the server side code to return exe file contents**

```
    //The context with which all SDK operations are performed.
Context context = Context.create();
String modelnumber = parameters.modelnumber;
String siteid=parameters.siteid;
def b;
try{

JSONArray arr=new  JSONArray();
    ModelFinder mf = new ModelFinder(context);
    mf.setName(modelnumber)

    Model m=mf.find();
    if(m!=null)
    {
        DeviceFinder df = new DeviceFinder(context);
        df.setModel(m)
        df.setSerialNumber(siteid)
        Device dev=df.find()
        if(dev!=null)

        {
            UploadedFileFinder  filefinder=new UploadedFileFinder(context)
            filefinder.setDevice(dev)
            filefinder.setFilename("/remote/notepad.exe")
            UploadedFile temp=filefinder.find()
            if(temp!=null)
            {
                    File f=temp.extractFile();
                    arr[0]=f.text
                    b=f.getBytes() 

            }
        }

    }

    return ['Content-Type': 'application/binary', 'Content':b];
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {       return ['Content-Type': 'application/text', 'Content':e.getMessage()];
    }
```

Comment: Why do you build the file in JS in the browser? Why don't you just let the browser download it from the server?

Comment: I cannot directly download it from server as i can only  return data from the server and somehow reuse data and develop exe

Comment: I don't understand what the difference between "download" and "return data from the server" could be.

Comment: The api provided at the server side is written in groovy.This api has method to send data and not the file directly to the browser.So at the client end we collect the bytes received from server and try to download it in the form of exe using the above code

Comment: *How* does the server send the bytes of the file? What are the HTTP headers?

Comment: I have added the server side code.Please check it

Comment: How did you solve it? You can answer our own question.

Comment: Please refer edited code. This code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I have solved the problem in following manner:**
>       **Server side code:**

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray() 
def bytes=file.getBytes()
                arr.add(bytes)

                return ['Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content': arr];
            }
```

**>    Client side code:**

```
value3 comes from ajax which is a byte array

      var arr =value3
                  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
                  var a = window.document.createElement('a');

                  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
                  a.download ="Utility.exe";

                  // Append anchor to body.
                  document.body.appendChild(a)
                  a.click();


                  // Remove anchor from body
                  document.body.removeChild(a)
```